# hello,any advice for adding TA-Lib

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, ta-lib

When trying to use a cmd in visual studio code Version: 1.53.2 (user setup)

Chrome: 87.0.4280.141

Node.js: 12.18.3

OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.19041

Python version 3.9.2..

This is my error, I have been at stand still for a day..pls help, Thanks Devs

```py
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\cash\coinview\.venv\scripts\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\CASH\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-zjh5g7bp\\ta-lib\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\CASH\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-zjh5g7bp\\ta-lib\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\CASH\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-jzlcw_4l\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 
'c:\users\cash\coinview\.venv\include\site\python3.9\TA-Lib' Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: It is not clear to me what command you are running, maybe include more detail.

Comment: @Vincent pip install TA_Lib in Visual Studio Code terminal using powershell as term

Comment: Im trying this post..--After much time I solved TA-Lib for windows
To build the 64-bit ta-lib.
Install TA-Lib C Library on Windows 10
Download and Unzip ta-lib-0.4.0-msvc.zip
Move the Unzipped Folder ta-lib to C:\
Download and Install Visual Studio Community 2015
Remember to Select [Visual C++] Feature
4. Build TA-Lib Library
From Windows Start Menu, Start [VS2015 x64 Native Tools Command Prompt]
Move to C:\ta-lib\c\make\cdr\win32\msvc
Build the Library nmake
5. Then pip3 install ta-lib. How do I get to c. I installed in c: then moved to c:ta-lib,cd c/ is not working to move forward

Comment: @vincent I tried with powershell wasn't working so I added git as a term in vsc then also added anaconda that allowed me to use pip install python-binance, But will not let the install TA-Lib go lol.

Comment: I got the specified location but command still wont take.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the [ta-lib native library](https://ta-lib.org/) before you can install the Python module that adds a Python API to that library.

I tried installing this module on my Mac before I installed the native library.  I got a very similar error:

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /Users/steve/envs/foo/bin/python -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/y2/84p16ph920x6j2g2glfb52pw0000gp/T/pip-install-U7_tLW/ta-lib/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/y2/84p16ph920x6j2g2glfb52pw0000gp/T/pip-install-U7_tLW/ta-lib/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/y2/84p16ph920x6j2g2glfb52pw0000gp/T/pip-record-OIbYo6/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /Users/steve/envs/foo/include/site/python2.7/TA-Lib Check the logs for full command output.
```

Then I did:

```
brew install ta-lib
```

to install the native library.  After doing that, the installation of the Python library worked just fine.

I don't know Windows, so I can't tell you how to install the native library.  It seems very likely, however, that that's the solution to your problem, just like it was mine.

Comment: Possibly helpful link to installing TA-Lib dependencies for other platforms: https://mrjbq7.github.io/ta-lib/install.html

Comment: Cool.  On Windows, the suggested install method is to place something at the root of your filesystem?  Windows often seems strange to me.

Comment: @CryptoFool thanks working on it I did get zip from ta-lib, saved to c:ta-lib but still not working. I need a mac ,also had problems installing twisted from not having wheel, So had to use setup.py. Wheel is for mac os?